# How do I add a custom text button to the control bar of the VideoJS Player v.7?

Tags: javascript, video.js

I have tried various snippets of code that I've found online, but I can't get any of them to work with the current version of VideoJS, which is version 7. I'm very new to javascript programming, and the documentation does not give example code on how to implement this. There is a codepen here that can be used to experiment with customizing the player: https://codepen.io/heff/pen/EarCt  This is the link to the VideoJS player documentation on adding a button to the player: https://docs.videojs.com/button

I've tried inserting code from various web page and 5-6 different discussions I found on StackExchange, but none of them make a button appear next to the video progress bar.

I'm simply trying to create a button with the text "Exit Course" that will appear to the right of the video progress bar, and that will execute a javascript function when pressed.

Could someone familiar with VideoJS please take a look at the codepen link above to see if they can add such a button to the player? Thank you!

I'm required to add some code to this question, so here is one piece of code that I tried on codepen:

```
var setup = {
                  'techOrder' : ['html5', 'flash'],
                  'controls' : true,
                  'preload' : 'auto',
                  'children':{
                      'controlBar': {
                          'children': {
                              'playbackSpeedPopoverMenu': {},
                              'selectBitrateControlButton': {src:videosrc},
                              'verticalVolumeMenuButton': {},
                              'volumeControl': false,
                              'muteToggle':false,
                              'liveDisplay':false,
                          }
                      }
                  };
var player = new vjs.Player(vjs.el("id_of_my_video_element_note_that_theres_no_poundsign"),
                            setup,
                            function() {
                               //this is your ready function
                            }));
```

Comment: Check this codepen: https://codepen.io/onigetoc/pen/wJRyvZ

Answer (score 5):

I've tested [this snippet](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/3473#issuecomment-238941307) with [video.js](/questions/tagged/video.js) 7.4.1 and it works fine. I used video.js's cancel icon instead of text to save space on the control bar. Give it a try:

```
<script>
  var player = videojs('my-player');
  var button = videojs.getComponent('Button');
  var closeButton = videojs.extend(button, {
    constructor: function() {
      button.apply(this, arguments);
      this.controlText("Exit Course");
      this.addClass('vjs-icon-cancel');
    },
    handleClick: function() {
      this.player().dispose();
    }
  });
  videojs.registerComponent('closeButton', closeButton);
  player.getChild('controlBar').addChild('closeButton', {});
</script>
```

Comment: Martin, thanks very much! I will try this in my project in the next few days. We have had to use a workaround for now as the project needed to be completed.

Answer (score 4):

```
var player = videojs('video');

var skipBehindButton = player.controlBar.addChild("button");
var skipBehindButtonDom = skipBehindButton.el();
skipBehindButtonDom.innerHTML = "30<<";
skipBehindButton.addClass("buttonClass");
    
skipBehindButtonDom.onclick = function(){
    skipS3MV(-30);
}  

var skipAheadButton = player.controlBar.addChild("button");
var skipAheadButtonDom = skipAheadButton.el();
skipAheadButtonDom.innerHTML = ">>30";
skipAheadButton.addClass("buttonClass");
    
skipAheadButtonDom.onclick = function(){
    skipS3MV(30);
}  

function skipS3MV(skipBy) {
    player.currentTime(player.currentTime() + skipBy);
}
```

[image]

The reason I've used text ("30<<" and ">>30") is because in my player, the colors are all customizable. So if I used an icon image for skip-back and skip-forward, then I wouldn't be able to change the color of the icon every time someone customizes the player colors (which includes the all the text in the control bar).